# Get data from URL PHP+ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have a question, I want to make profile page to let's say I'll add a link on data from DB

```
<a href=index.php?page_id=profile&id=NAME></a>
```

Now In profile page I want this name to be taken from previous link in order to use it to get data from DB.

```php
if (isset($_GET['profile'])) { 
    $Profile = $core_db->Execute("Select ID, Name, Age, Nationality, Age from Profiles where Name='NAME'");
    if ($_GET['profile'] == 'NAME') {
        echo 'Profile DATA That I want to show from DB';
    }
}
```

So how to make `if ($_GET['profile'] == 'NAME')` to be taken from Page URL to use When Name=? to get the data?

I'm sorry I might not be able to describe what I want well.
Thanks for your concern.

Comment: If you have problems, usual thing to try is `print_r($_GET);` to see what values you are getting, you may find it's `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Can you give example I'm not that good with PHP

Comment: Please try to use [Parameterized Queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php) so that you don't suffer from [Lil' Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Thank you guys I got what I needed by using $Profile = htmlspecialchars($_GET["profile"]);
Special thanks to Nigel Ren